# How to run jsp netbeans glass fish on local ip 192.168.1.165

Tags: jsp, glassfish, netbeans6.5

I am trying to run a jsp app on my machine ip: 192.168.1.165 and want to get it in system with ip 192.168.1.163

but giving the url

http://192.168.1.165:port/app

is not working

( we are working in intranet. )

Pls, help me...

how to make this possible.

Comment: Not programming related. Belongs on serverfault.

Comment: I'll will avoid these questions in future. Thanks for intimation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://192.168.1.165:8000/app

http://192.168.1.165:8080/app

http://192.168.1.165:6747/app

If not working, double check firewall on server and your computer